# How load varchar into date type in SQL Server using Informatica?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Error while moving data from one table (`nvarchar`) to another table (`date`) within SQL Server 2014 using IICS (Informatica Cloud). I tried using expression

```
To_date_out = To_date(Incep_Date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

but the same error still shows up:

> TT_11019 There is an error in the port [Incep_Date]: The default value for the port is set to: ERROR(Transformation error: IUpdateStrategyNode12)[image]

Comment: In an expression, you do not do the assignment.  Just put `to_date(incep_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')`.  No need for the `to_date_out =` part.

Comment: additionally, be sure that your incoming nvarchar dates are formatted exactly like the  format string you are specifying (yyyy-mm-dd).  if perhaps, those come from a text field somewhere, a user may not have properly entered the date.

Comment: Thanks bitbangs.Although I’ve shown here both output port & exprsn, I’ve put only the latter as you mentioned i.e.not with the assignment. The format appears YYYY-MM-DD in source table with data type nvarchar & I’ve tried all different formats, trimmed etc - same error. As expected, I verified it writing to target file & it writes in YYYY-MM-DD successfully,but when target is another table - it fails. Goal :Nvarchar -> Date within SQL server using Informatica.

Comment: Looked up the error message TT_11019. It appears that you have a [string port linked to a date](https://kb.informatica.com/solution/15/Pages/115227.aspx) and you need to edit your session-level datetime formatting or change the formatting your doing in your expression to match whatever your session is set to.

Comment: Yep-Same post I guess I looked up yesterday too. Tried changing format as per session and am here to solve error that comes up while doing so.

Comment: hmmm..are you able to share a screenshot of the ports of IUpdateStrategyNode12?

Comment: Yes @bitbangs. For this example, only one port with nvarchar column in source table, which is stored in a column in target table with just 1 col i.e. Date data type. I've attached the expression screenshot as the source(just selected the table) & target (slect tgt table with auto mapping) have no change

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It seems Informatica implicitly converts the varchar in YYYY-MM-DD to YYYY/MM/DD, despite the session and the source data in a different(former) format.So in the expression, we need to convert to the latter format & it works! TO_DATE( Incep_Date, ‘YYYY-MM-DD’). Thanks @bitbangs for your time & help.